# Trying to call a function within another function

Tags: python, function

What I (think) I'm trying to do is to call a previously defined function, inside another function and I'm getting the error "cannot access local variable 'f' where it is not associated with a value". My code is this one:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ethaf = 10 # final value
def f(t, r):
    f,fp,fpp=r
    dfdn = fp
    dfpdn = fpp
    dfppdn = -0.5*f*fpp
    return dfdn, dfpdn, dfppdn
    
fpp = 0.4 # guess
y0 = [0, 0, fpp]
t = np.linspace(0, ethaf, 101)
sol = solve_ivp(f, (0,ethaf), y0, t_eval=t)

def SM(fpp):
    sol = solve_ivp(f, (0, ethaf), y0, vectorized=True)
    f, fp, fpp = sol.y
    return sol.y[1]

fpp = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 500)
plt.plot(fpp, SM(fpp))
plt.grid(linewidth=0.8, linestyle='--', alpha=0.6)
```

I have read other questions about this topic and they have left wondering what's actually wrong with my code and how do I fix it. The error I'm getting is the next one:

```
> UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[3], line 37
>      34     return sol.y[1]
>      36 fpp = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 500)
> ---> 37 plt.plot(fpp, SM(fpp))
>      38 plt.grid(linewidth=0.8, linestyle='--', alpha=0.6)
> 
> Cell In[3], line 32, in SM(fpp)
>      31 def SM(fpp):
> ---> 32     sol = solve_ivp(f, (0, ethaf), y0, vectorized=True)
>      33     f, fp, fpp = sol.y
>      34     return sol.y[1]
> 
> UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'f' where it is not
> associated with a value
```

Comment: The mere assignment to `f` on line 2 of `SM` makes it a local variable, meaning it shadows *global* variable `f` you attempt to use in line 1. Use a different variable name.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error happens.  Please update the question to include the **full** error message.

Comment: Opps, got that wrong. chepner is correct. `f, fp, fpp = sol.y` makes `f` a local variable for that function.